# How to access tabBarItem from ViewController inside of NavigationController embedded in TabController?

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have a UITabBarController that contains a UINavigationController that contains a UITableViewController.

How do I access the tabBarItem inside the table view controller?

I tried `self.navigationItem.tabBarItem.title = @"Something";` but that throws a compiler error:

```
Property 'tabBarItem' not found on object of type 'UINavigationItem *'
```

Answer (score 1):

The tabBarItem is on the View Controller, not the Navy Item. Try

```
self.navigationController.tabBarItem.title = @"something";
```

Comment: Well, that doesn't throw an error, but it doesn't set the title of the tab bar.